# Use Bing in Worldwind Android

Tags: android, worldwind

> Use Bing Imagery in Worldwind Android

How can i use bing imagery in Worldwind Android?

is this the right way?

```
WmsLayerConfig config = new WmsLayerConfig();
    config.serviceAddress = "http://www.microsoft.com/maps/assets/docs/terms.aspx/";
```

Answer (score 1):

NASA hosts a WMS service for Bing. Try this:

```
//Bing hybrid
String serviceAddress = "https://worldwind27.arc.nasa.gov/wms/virtualearth?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS";
WmsLayerConfig config = new WmsLayerConfig();
config.serviceAddress = serviceAddress;
config.wmsVersion = "1.3.0";
config.layerNames = "ve-h"; //ve-h for hybrid, ve-r for street
WmsLayer wmsLayer = new WmsLayer(new Sector().setFullSphere(), 1, config);
wwd.getLayers().addLayer(wmsLayer);
```